# Make CSS menu item load website instead of changing placeholder with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, menu

I have a css menu, but when I try and load a url from the menu, like google in the example. It only changes the name of the placeholder and doesn't load the page. Any idea how to change this?

Thanks for help!

Fiddle example, try to load google in the menu : http://jsfiddle.net/n877s/3/

```
            function DropDown(el) {
            this.dd = el;
            this.placeholder = this.dd.children('span');
            this.opts = this.dd.find('ul.dropdown > li');
            this.val = '';
            this.index = -1;
            this.initEvents();
        }
        DropDown.prototype = {
            initEvents : function() {
                var obj = this;

                obj.dd.on('click', function(event){
                    $(this).toggleClass('active');
                    return false;
                });

                obj.opts.on('click',function(){
                    var opt = $(this);
                    obj.val = opt.text();
                    obj.index = opt.index();
                    obj.placeholder.text(obj.val);
                });
            },
            getValue : function() {
                return this.val;
            },
            getIndex : function() {
                return this.index;
            }
        }

        $(function() {

            var dd = new DropDown( $('#dd') );

            $(document).click(function() {
                // all dropdowns
                $('.wrapper-dropdown-3').removeClass('active');
            });

        });
```

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper-demo">
<div id="dd" class="wrapper-dropdown-3" tabindex="1">
    <span>Transport</span>
        <ul class="dropdown">
        <li><a href="#">Classic mail</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">UPS Delivery</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a></li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

​

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are preventing the standard behavior of links (even the descendent links) right here:

```
        obj.dd.on('click', function(event){
            $(this).toggleClass('active');
            return false;
        });
```

Add the following code to prevent clicks on the menu items from bubbling up to the above handler:

```
        obj.dd.find('a').on('click',function(event){
            event.stopPropagation();
        });
```

Here's a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n877s/4/).

Note: check the console to see the result, as jsfiddle won't load google.com in its iframe (SAMEORIGIN policy).

Answer (score 1):

Your `<a>` tags are descendants of the `<div id="dd">`, and that div has a `click` handler which returns `false` and suppresses the default click action. The click event is generated on the `a` tag and bubbles up to the `div` which suppresses it.

One way to make it work would be to add this:

```
if ($(event.target).is("a[href!=#]"))
    return true;
```

just above the `return false;` line

Answer (score 1):

Method #1: The easiest way would be to remove `return false;` from obj.dd's click event and add `event.stopPropagation();` at the start of it and then just give your link href attributes a value and they'll load that page. Like so:

```
obj.dd.on('click', function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();

    $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

Method #2: Or you could try:

```
obj.opts.on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var opt = $(this);
    obj.val = opt.text();
    obj.index = opt.index();
    obj.placeholder.text(obj.val);

    window.location.href = opt.attr('href');
});
```

And in HTML, add links similar to the google link you have.